# Comment Section Not Appearing in Blogger

Tags: comments, blogs, blogger, missing-features

For some reason the comment section isn't appearing on my blog (hosted by Blogger) and I can't figure out why. I'm not sure if it's a glitch in the template or if I deleted something I shouldn't have while customizing it.

I tried the Settings -> Posts, comments, and sharing -> Comments -> Embedded and it's still not working.

http://aislinlookingforsomething.blogspot.ca/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the existing theme, It looks a template problem. Use dynamic templates rather than using blogger internal themes